# Can AngularJS Factory return two different instances

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

```
'use strict';
(function(){
    function myFactory(){
         var model = {};
         function viewModelManager(){
            return {
               getInstance : function(){
                   return model;
             }
         }
         return viewModelManager;
    }

}
 angular.module('main').factory('viewModelFactory',myFactory);
} ());
```

In reference to above code snippet, I want to know the difference between below two invocations :

```
    new viewModelFatory();
```

and

```
    viewModelFactory();
```

Both seem to be returning object which is returned by viewModelManager function. Then what is the advantage of using operator new?

Also is my understanding correct about above code snippet :
1) that viewModelFatory will only have one single instance and whenever we inject it into multiple controllers it will refer to that instance.
2) that viewModelFactory can be used to create multiple stateful instances given that I create these instance variables inside viewModelManager function?
3) whenever I call new viewModelFatory()(OR viewModelFactory()), it will create a new instance of viewModelManager function?

Answer (score 3):

> Can AngularJS Factory return two different instances?

AngularJS Providers are **singletons**. Using the `new` keyword will not create a new factory. However methods of a factory can create new instances.

As example, the `getInstance` method of your factory can create new instances.

```
'use strict';
(function(){
    function myFactory(){
         var modelID = 0;
         function Model(id) {
             this.id = id;
         };
         function viewModelManager(){
            return {
               getInstance : function() {
                   return new Model(modelID++);
             }
         }
         return viewModelManager;
    }
}
 angular.module('main').factory('viewModelFactory',myFactory);
} ());
```

In the above example, the first call to `viewModelFactory.getInstance()` will return an instance of the `Model` object with the `id` property equal to zero. The next call to `viewModelFactory.getInstance()` will return an instance with the `id` property incremented to one. Subsequent calls will create instances with the `id` property similarly incremented.

To reiterate, AngularJS factories are **singletons**. However factory **methods** can create different instances.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

With `new`, unlike `new()` you can call something like this:

```
new factoryService.ConstructorFactory();
```

So you could return different methods by calling them:

```
    var ConstructorA= function () {
        return 'A'
    };

    var ConstructorB= function () {
      return 'B';  
    };
    return {
        ConstructorA: ConstructorA,
        ConstructorB: ConstructorB
    };
```

So in your code you are returning a `viewModelManager` instance

Comment: it doesn't answer my questions

Comment: what is the advantage of using new operator if I am getting the same result without using it ?

Comment: I am returning a viewModelManager instance everytime I invoke viewModelFatory() or new viewModelFatory() but they will always be different. is this correct? if yes what should we use and what advantage one gives over the other?

Comment: The reason to call new on an object is if it is using prototypal inheritance.  This is not your case here so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the code is supposed to look like this:

```
'use strict';
(function(){
    function myFactory(){
         var model = {};
         function viewModelManager(){
            return {
               getInstance : function(){
                   return model;
             }
         }
         return viewModelManager;
    }
}
 angular.module('main').factory('viewModelFactory',myFactory);
} ());
```

note the placement of the `return viewModelManager`  line.

That said, if my assumption is correct, then here is what happens:

The first time 'viewModelFactory' is found as an injected dependency in another component, angular will execute the myFactory function. The viewModelFactory is equal to the return value of the myFactory function which is viewModelManger. Then, if you use like this:

```
new viewModelFactory()
```

you will be given a new viewModelManger object (prototype viewModelManager) (i.e. the viewModelManager function is executed as a constructor), this object will not have any properties.

Whereas if you use is like this:

```
viewModelFactory()
```

you will be given the return value of the viewModelManager function which will have prototype Object and a method getInstance.

Edit:
Hmmm nevermind, I just learned that if you return explicitly from a constructor, that will override default constructor behavior.